# Javascript array filter out numbers represented as strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array like this:

```
a = ["name","text","dog","1","2","cat"]
```

I want to filter out all the numbers represented as strings (integers and floats) from the above given array. In this case I want to filter out "1", "2"

**Desired Output**

```
a=["name","text","dog","cat"]
```

**Note:** I am looking for a clean and elegant way to solve this. A naive approach that comes to my mind is to try and typecast to a float (which would cover both integers and floats) and if it fails, only then I should include the element in the array. I was wondering if there is a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the array using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and only keep the elements that are not numbers using [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

```js
const a = ["name","text","dog","1","2","cat",".2"];

const res = a.filter(isNaN);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Great, this works! Can you explain a little as to why?

Comment: My use case was for numbers and that is what I intended, sorry for the confusion. I can edit the Question to make that clearer

Comment: isNaN('2005/12/12') //true what do you think? you says?

Comment: Number.isInteger('2005/12/12'); //false, what do you mean integer?

Comment: @SeniorWebEngineer this value is not a number, neither an integer. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: You're right! it is checked which is not a number